# How to make Dynamic textbox multiline with 10 rows

Tags: asp.net

I have created dynamic textbox in code behind, but I want to make that textbox multiline with 10 rows, Could you please tell how to make its TextMode as MultiLine.
I have tried following code:

```
TextBox _textDesc = new TextBox();

_textDesc.ID = "textDesc_" + i.ToString();
_textDesc.MaxLength = 200;
_textDesc.TextMode = "MultiLine";
_textDesc.Rows = 10;
_textDesc.Columns = 20;
tdDesctxt.Controls.Add(_textDesc);
```

But it is showing error at: `_textDesc.TextMode = "MultiLine";`

Answer (score 4):

`TextMode` is a property of type `TextBoxMode`, not `string`:

> _textDesc.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;

[Read more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textboxmode.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Simply add it like this:

```
            //decorate the TextBox.
            _textDesc.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
            _textDesc.Wrap = true;
```

Remember you can always press Ctrl+space right after the Dot to get more.